# Four probe vs Two probe method

Tags: electronic-band-theory

In an experiment where we have to measure the resistivity of a semiconductor, or it's band gap energy, we use the four probe method, instead of two probe. So what is the advantage of the four probe method over the two probe method?

Here is the experiment I'm talking about: http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=1&brch=282&sim=1512&cnt=1

Comment: Have done anything to answer your own question e.g. googling to get a link like http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S2010194513010970

Comment: Yes I did. I was looking for a more detailed answer. I think : In the two probe method, suppose there is some effect of minority carrier injection and we get an extra electron. This electron may not combine fast enough to leave the actual resistivity more or less unchanged. Whereas in the four probe method, the electron travels a relatively longer distance and recombines. And the voltage is measured at a probe different from that of the incoming current, so the resistivity measured is not much affected. Am I thinking right?